# POST Behavior Between $http and Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a simple ASP.NET Web API 2 service. I'm new at Angular, but I'm trying to switch from using $http to Restangular. My GET appears to be fine, but my POST is not.

The code looks like this:

```
    $scope.addLift = function () {
    $http.post(url, $scope.Lift);
    //Restangular.all('lifts').post('Lift', $scope.Lift).then(function (newLift) {
    //    $scope.getLifts();
    //}, function (error) {
    //    console.log(error);
    //});
};
```

The commented out Restangular code does not work, but the $http.post does and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If it's helpful, the POST when using Restangular is `http://localhost/api/lifts?LiftName=test` where in the `$http` POST request, it does not contain the parameters on the URL line, it seems the data is in the request body.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on another website was kind enough to help me through this. Thought I would post the answer in hopes that it might benefit others.

```
Restangular.all('lifts').post($scope.Lift).then(function (newLift) {
        $scope.getLifts();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The additional `'lift'` argument was not necessary in the `post` call.